# Disable notification spam at end of do not disturb schedule

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s7, do-not-disturb

I'm using a Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0.0 and Samsung experience 9.0.

At the end of the do not disturb schedule all my notifications come through at once. All I hear is just the notification sound being spammed repeatedly for every notification that was suppressed while do not distrurb was enabled. This never used to happen, it would just come out of do not disturb mode and no sound would be played for old notifications. This seems like a bug. Is there a way to stop this?

This may be a Galaxy S7 specific question, I can never seem to tell which is a core Android issue and which is Samsung specific. The articles I have seen on do not disturb for Oreo look quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like an Oreo issue as documented here:

https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/26/feature-bug-oreo-dnd-turns-off-get-barraged-sounds-vibrations-pending-received-notifications/

It was resolved in 8.1.0, but Samsung hasn't provided this update to its 8.0 phones. So today it is mostly Samsung users that are affected.

https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S9-Questions-and-Answers/S9-notifications-after-do-not-disturb-goes-off/m-p/371390#M7828